# The hook drop down

Tags: word-usage, grammar

I stuck two wall hook on the wall and place the basketball board on them.

One of the hook fell down.

> "The hook drop down."
>
> "The hook fell down."

If a thing drop from a wall, we use drop or fell?

Do they have different meaning?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Both are idiomatic in this context. But remember you need the past tense "The hook *dropped* down".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both convey the meaning of ending up down on the floor. Someone might disagree but "**drop**" mostly means "*to fall straight down*" so logically "**fell**" would be a better choice, however this is only an assumption.